# How to get the records where status is equal to nil and not equal to privilage or casual

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a `leave` table. in this i have a `status` column. which is a string column.i want to get those records from `leave` table where `status` column is equal to `null` and status not equal to `privilage` or `casual` or `sick`. how to write this query in rails 4 ?

```
leave.where(:status => nil).where.not(:status => "casual" or "privilage" or "sick").
```

Comment: you have a strange condition, because you search to status eq nil, and also status not casual|priveledge|sick, so you just get the always records, where status is nil

Comment: `status` is `null` and has either of those values?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
leave.where(status: nil).where.not(status: %w[casual privilage sick])
```

Comment: Wait! If you get records with `nil` status, they automatically not `casual` or `privilage` or `sick`. May be you need `OR` condition between `nil` and other status values?

Comment: 2.2.2 :072 > PunchInOut.where(status: nil).where.not(status: %w[casual privilage sick])
  PunchInOut Load (1.1ms)  SELECT `punch_in_outs`.* FROM `punch_in_outs`  WHERE `punch_in_outs`.`status` IS NULL AND (`punch_in_outs`.`status` NOT IN ('casual', 'privilage', 'sick'))
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> 
2.2.2 :073 >

Comment: so many records satisfying this criteria are present. but iam getting emty array.

Comment: @John `but iam getting emty array.` yes , that because of the requirements (see my answer)

Comment: i think between the two where conditions, instead of and it should be or condition in the sql query. how to get or operator?

Comment: I thought a lot about it. While Rails 5 still in beta (http://www.notch8.com/rails-5-activerecord-changes/), we could use direct Arel interface like this:

`arel_table = Leave.arel_table`
`leave.where(arel_table[:status].eq(nil).or(arel_table[:status].in(%w[casual privilage sick])))`

You can also pass direct SQL `WHERE` clause into the `where` method.

In case of your example two `where` conditions may be redundant and I agree with the @МалъСкрылевъ answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need something like this (trying brain reading ability 
;-) ):

```
leave.where.not(status: ['casual', 'privilage', 'sick', nil ])
```

or may be

```
leave.where.not(status: nil).where.not(status: %w(casual privilage sick))
```